# Parallel insertion sort with k sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, parallel-processing

I am trying to use threads to sort an array, what is needed is that only the k first elemenst in the array are sorted in decreasing order while the rest is not, but the k first numbers needs to be the largest numbers in the array.

The way I went by doing this was first sequentially sorting the k first elements in the array, then give sub arrays of the rest of the array to the threads, where the threads will only check their array if there is a number larger that k-1(the smallest number in k) then insert it into the right position in k.

When trying this with n=10million k=100 and threads=8 the parallel code is twice as slow as the sequential one.

Is my algorithm bad? How would you go by making it parallel.

Ps. I know threading insertion sort is not effecient, just want to see if its a good way to try

Comment: It might help to see your code but I'd assume you are synchronizing on the array in order to do the insert which may effectively turn parallel execution into sequential.

Comment: @Thomas i only use the join(), I tried doing synch(this) in the run when changing values of the array but this made no difference

Comment: If you're not synchronizing then having multiple threads move around elements in the same array is bound to lead to errors as those operations aren't atomic. But I'll repeat my statement: without seeing code it's hard to help more. So please share a [mcve].